# GPU EVGA XC 2070 Super fans doesn't spin at idle

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan, temperature

Just finished building my new PC, with a graphics card EVGA XC 2070 Super, and noticed that at idle, the GPU fans does not spin. With temperatures of about 47-50C. They do spin while booting, so I know they work, and I saw them spinning really slow once while on windows, with temps or around 54C. I installed the drivers from EVGA website and that didn't make any difference.

I am used to my old pc where my GPU fans will spin all the time and ramp up when the temperature increase, so I am not sure if with newer GPUs, is it normal to have the fans not spinning at idle?

Comment: The [EVGA software](https://www.evga.com/precisionx1/) should allow you to override the fan profile.  However, unless this profile is actually a problem, you shouldn’t change it

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty normal that your GPU fan is not spinning in idle condition.Because modern Graphic cards have the function that their fans will start when temprature will be 50-55c.and they will automatically stop after cooling upto 30 to 35c and they will remain stop when gpu will be in idle condition.so there is no reason to worry about it.More you can read that guide to satisfy yourself.
https://techmotherboard.com/gpu-fan-not-spinning/
Thanks